# Display selection list for user input

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

**We are using Classic pipelines (not YAML)**. Our code repos contain Visual Studio projects for SSIS packages. Currently each repo only contains one SSIS package, so when you do a build a predefined variable is used to create the build artifact from the package. Our desire is to allow folks to have multiple SSIS packages in one repo (project based) and then when doing a pipeline build select which package(s) to build and release.

My preferred solution would be this:

1. When the build is executed a PowerShell script enumerates the SSIS packages to populate a variable.
2. SSIS package names are displayed as checkboxes, allowing the user to select which packages to include in the build.
3. Build artifact is created using the selected SSIS packages.

If that is not possible with DevOps Pipelines, I'd settle for this alternative solution:

1. When DevOps Pipeline is created (or edited), user populates a variable with the list of SSIS package names in their repo.
2. When the build is executed the SSIS package names are displayed as checkboxes, allowing the user to select which packages to include in the build.
3. Build artifact is created using the selected SSIS packages.

I want to reiterate that we already have working Pipelines that create artifacts for release from SSIS packages. So I am not starting from scratch, I'm merely trying to modify our process to build and release selected SSIS packages from a group. I have spent many hours digging around in the docs and help forums, but have yet to find a way to do this. I'm all ears for any suggestions from the experts here on SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am afraid above prefered solution isnot possible. For there is no way to display a checkbox during the execution of the build to allow user to select to build which packages.

However, to populates a variable  When DevOps Pipeline is created (or edited) is achievable. See below:

1, Create variables in the Variables tab (check `Settable at queue time`)

[image]

2, Add multiple build tasks in your pipeline, one for each package. Use the [customized condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to decide which package should be build. See below:

Select **Custom conditons**-->And enter condtion expression `and(succeeded(), eq(variables.APackageOne, true))`

[image]

3, When use queue the pipeline, He should modify the variables values to select which packages should be built:

[image]

Using yaml pipeline and [runtime parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script) would be better for above case.

1, You can define multiple runtime parameters as flag for each of the packages. And use condition to decide which package should be build according the parameter use selected. See below:

```
parameters:
- name: Package One
  type: boolean
  default: false
- name: PackageTwo
  type: boolean
  default: false
- name: PackageThree
  type: boolean
  default: false
- name: PackageFour
  type: boolean
  default: false
```

If above parameters is defined in your yaml pipeline. You can select the packages when user queues the pipeline. See  Below:

[image]

Then use customized conditions to only build the selected packages:

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  name: BuildPackageOne
  inputs:
    ...
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq('${{ parameters.PackageOne }}', true))
```

Comment: That's what I was seeing too, all of this seems easier if you're using YAML. Unfortunately we have dozens of pipelines already in place using the Classic method. But thanks for the great answer! I'm glad to know what our options are.